# SwiftUI prevent List in Sheet from inheriting parent Form styles

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

How can I prevent a view within a Sheet from inheriting components from its parents?

I believed a Sheet would create a whole new view hierarchy, but apparently it does not completely. As seen in the Gif below, the `ListView` inherits the Form when it is attached to the Button inside the Form. When placing it outside the form, the List behaves as expected. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? As you can see, the list with its sections becomes pretty useless when inheriting the Form. This almost seems like a bug to me.

*Tested in an empty project using Xcode Version 12.5 (12E262) and iOS 14.5*

[image]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isSheetPresented: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                NavigationLink ("Link", destination: ListView())
                Button("Sheet") {
                    isSheetPresented = true
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetPresented, content: {
                    NavigationView {
                        ListView()
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button("1") { }
            Button("2") { }
            Button("3") { }
            Section(header: Text("one")) {
                Button("4") { }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("List")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DefaultListStyle()`

```
ListView().listStyle(DefaultListStyle())
```

Comment: Thank you, was just about to post this. This did indeed solve the problem, do you have any idea why a sheet inherits the Form?

Comment: First, this is not a bug but the Form has its own style/behavior. When you put only a normal list or with a sheet it will part of the Form. Same as NavigationView.

Comment: A small note, when wrapping the list in a navigation view, `PlainListStyle` is required instead of `DefaultListStyle` to explicitly get the type of list as requested above.